# Align a vertical centered flex element to the right

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a div that is vertically centered using flex box. But is there now any way to align it to the right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option would be to add `justify-content: flex-end` to the flexbox container: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/guuu52th/)

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.parent > .child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also add `margin-left: auto` to the flexbox item: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfxhot84/)

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    align-items: center;
}
.parent > .child {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: margin-left: auto; did the job. Thank you a lot! justify-content: flex-end; won't because it needs to be centered vertically.

Comment: Actually it works with justify-content: flex-end; too if the parent element has flex-direction: row; instead of flex-direction: column;